# How to reduce Nginx tasks running under php-fpm?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, memory, php-fpm, mod-php

What is Apache's mod_php equivalent in Nginx? I have Nginx with php-fpm. Everything is perfect but the problem is that it works like fcgi in Apache not mod_php. This means that a task is added for every host I add. I have 50 hosts with few static pages and negligible traffic, but I have a php5-fpm task for each which uses about 25M of RAM. Thus, I have 2 running task and 50+ sleeping tasks using 1GB of RAM.

fcgi is useful for security reason as each host has its own task; but in a server with single user, mod_php saves RAM as all tasks are running under apache user. How can I do this Nginx?

Comment: There is none, nginx is not designed for Shared hosting and it (most likely) never will be.

Comment: In shared hosting we need to run hosts under different users (i.e. various clients). I am talking about a single server for a single admin.

Comment: Then I think you misunderstand how php-fpm works. You don't need a dedicated process to each host, you can fastcgi pass to the same host so long as you do not need user separation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run php-fpm pools with different user rights, and proxy fastcgi requests to each pool depending on the domain.

There was [a tutorial about this](http://www.howtoforge.com/php-fpm-nginx-security-in-shared-hosting-environments-debian-ubuntu) a few weeks ago at howtoforge.com, I hope it helps.